# Intel Graphic 945 driver for ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, drivers

I'm new to the forum, and Ubuntu as well. i have installed the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS along with the windows 7, the installation went fine. but the problem is i cannot install my graphic driver. I have Intel 945.I searched in the site also and found that its driver is obsolete so anyone please help me to install my graphic driver.

Thank in advance.

Comment: does not work for me: get response The following packages have unmet dependencies: xserver-xorg-video-intel: Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>=2:1.10.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
--------------------------------------------------------------------- Going back to Windows that does this all automatically????

Answer (score 3):

Drop into your terminal and issue the following commands;

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

 sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Now you need to create a config file;

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Then paste this into the file;

```
Section "Device" 
Identifier "Card0" 
Driver "intel" 
Option "AccelMethod" "sna" 
EndSection
```

Save the file and give your machine a reboot.  You should now have the correct driver installed.

Comment: This also solved my problem over at http://askubuntu.com/questions/491506/second-monitor-recognized-but-only-black-screen

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems and solved them by updating kernel to 3.5.x+ and install fresh xorg-video-intel:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-intel-dbg
```