# Upgrade from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 Multiple Display not Detected Nvidia GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, 17.10, display

Upgrading from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 went smoothly with the commands found [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver). I found others use the software manager but I could not get my software manager to find the upgrade, I suspect it may be that the repos are being deprecated.

I could only get a singular grainy 1024x768 display to show on my dual monitor. This was in contrast to my HD display in 17.10. I tried the fixes by installing lightdm via

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829108/what-is-gdm3-kdm-lightdm-how-to-install-and-remove-them) which did not fix the issue. At this point, tried checking what `xrandr` returned (recommended [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25120/xrandr-doesnt-detect-monitor-on-hdmi-port)) but it only returned that it could not detect the displays or information on the display, e.g.

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

thus giving me the default grainy 1024x768 display (found information [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227876/how-to-set-custom-resolution-using-xrandr-when-the-resolution-is-not-available-i))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, I suspected that this could be a driver problem. I tried to check additional drivers, which is now in the software and updates application (see screenshot). I read on [Nvidia](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1035768/ubuntu-18-04-can-t-see-second-monitor/) that rolling back could help the problem. Originally, my driver was set to Nvidia 396, denoted as proprietary but not tested. I chose the Nvidia 390 option listed in the software and updates, as I've had prior problems with xorg with nvidia gpus. This solved my issue.

[image: Nvidia Driver 390]