# fsck at boot - Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, boot, fsck

My Dell Inspiron 3542 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS runs fsck every time it boots and therefore i cannot get past the boot splash screen - anything to do ? can i remove 12.04 completely and install 14.04LTS ?

Comment: I think Ubuntu always runs fsck at start (I thought it did it only from ubuntu 15.04 and later but I guess I was wrong). If you se a message like this: `/dev/sda6: clean, 121539/6234222 files, 1053787/24914550 blocks` then this is not a problem only if it shows more errors. See also this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/777241/lubuntu-16-04-fresh-install-stuck-on-boot/777257#777257.

Answer (score 0):

A running fsck at startup indicates that you have a problem with your partition on your disk.

Run this when you are at prompt

```
e2fsck -y /dev/sdx#
```

Where "#" is the disk interface you have installed Ubuntu, to correct the problem.

Alternatively, maybe there is a option in your fstab file and runs all the time because of this.

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=136f3cdf-c824-4f8a-8bac-d86faaf17f63 / ext3 errors=remount-ro 0 1
# /home was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=eb55f063-766c-45fd-8ee3-93f33cc735b5 /home ext3 defaults 0 2
```

The numbers "1" or "2" in the last column controls when fsck runs. If you change it to "0" fsck will not run.

Good Luck.

If the problem persist it must be a hardware problem or a damaged disk.

Another approach.

Remove any USB you have on your laptop. Sometimes the excessive current drawn from your USB ports may cause a malfunction of your hard drive in general.