# lubuntu 16.04 installed, then hangs

Tags: boot, 16.04, lubuntu, ssd

EEE 1000HE with 2GB RAM and 240GB SSD. lubuntu desktop i386 (32-bit) 16.04 booted from the SD card.

I installed to a new SSD and indicated a reboot was needed.  After reboot the machine hangs with the message:

/dev/sda1: clean, 128835/14524416 files, 1693315/58085376 blocks

I have tried to install lubuntu twice.  The SSD is new and I assume that lubuntu install disk takes care of formatting the filesystem on the SSD.  Maybe this is incorrect it is necessary to prep the SSD before installing lubuntu?  I am not sure if I am asking the right question to understand why it is installation is not successful.

After failed install attempt, I tried to invoke 'Try lubuntu without installing' and the screen goes dark.  Removed Logitech mouse USB and tried to invoke 'Try lubuntu without installing' and machine responded differently with text (too fast to see) and ends up with a blinking underscore in the upper left corner.

## Update:

**Success install performed with lubuntu 15.10**

A similar attempt was made with the 'heavier' Ubuntu 16.04.  Ubuntu bootup 'Try Ubuntu without installing' (TUWI) was successful, as well as the install to the SSD.

Although I am relieved that at least one form of Ubuntu is working, I would like to understanding why the lubuntu does not install  and why the TUWI modes fail.  Ubuntu is a little 'heavy' for this hardware and lubuntu would be snappier.

Comment: You should not edit your question to give your answer but create your own answer to your question.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don't put the answer in your question or the comments! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Successful install  with lubuntu 15.10**

Lesson-learned: sometimes an older version will work when the newest does not.

Comment: Please try 14.04 instead. It's an LTS version. Unlike 15.10, it will still be supported with security updates after the end of this month.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful LTS suggestion.  Because the user had significant Windows experience we landed on xUbuntu 16.04