# Hp laptop not booting Lubuntu after upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, lubuntu, hp

I'm pretty new to linux (specifically Lubuntu) and my HP Mini 110 isn't booting after upgrading to the latest version of the ubuntu base, Ubuntu 17.10. Instead of booting, I get a screen with garbled colorful pixels slowly forming from left to right at the top and some text reading "/dev/sda29: clean, 201172/4587520 files, 3231575/18328064 blocks". The mouse cursor appears and even the brightness controls work, but nothing else will load. I've already tried the solutions listed here from this guy who seemed to have a similar problem: [Lubuntu 16.04 fresh install stuck on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777241/lubuntu-16-04-fresh-install-stuck-on-boot). Can anyone help?

Thanks,

AgentK.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue (Lubuntu 17.10 and an HP Mini 110) and solved it using suggestions from this link:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384579&p=13738255#post13738255

The issue involves a video setting that is incorrect.

1. While booting hit ctrl-alt-F1
2. Log into terminal
3. The bottom line of the terminal is annoyingly below the bottom of the screen, but what you type is still there, just hidden
4. type sudo vi /etc/default/grub (or nano or your favorite editor)
5. type under the commented out line "GRUB_GFXMODE":
       GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x600
6. save file
7. type sudo update-grub
8. type sudo reboot

It now should work. With my new drive and added memory I have a ridiculously underpowered machine with a 1TB drive and 2 GB of memory

Comment: +1, I still have one of these I'm keeping going too!