# How to fix this error in14.04?

Tags: graphics, intel

This occurs all the time when I use Ubuntu:
[image: 1]

I run Ubuntu in  2GB RAM
                 processor Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E7500 @ 2.93GHz × 2
                 Graphics  Intel® 945G x86/MMX/SSE2
                 OS type   32 bit
                 disk      155.3

I think all this is enough for Ubuntu to run, but I don't know what happened.

Please, help me!

Comment: Your computer does indeed meet the minimum requirements to run Ubuntu. But what is the error you are receiving and when does it occur?

Comment: Why it doesn't meet? Its CPU and RAM looks fine. Yet @Jyothinath didn't mention the error.

Comment: You may need the xorg.conf mentioned here http://askubuntu.com/questions/370922/intel-graphic-945-driver-for-ubuntu-12-04-lts (but not adding the PPA or installing)

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha While I'm Working on ubutnu the screen goes off and comes like this...but when i use windows in the same pc nothing occurs...and windows runs perfectly fine...its the problem with ubuntu ...its 32bit os gnu/linux for educational purpose...

Comment: when i run the same ubuntu in virtualbox...no problem

Comment: If now you are running new version of Ubuntu, please open new question.